# nginx 403 Forbidden static files on digitalocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, digital-ocean

There is a file `sample.csv` in public folder.

```
<%= link_to 'Sample File', root_url+'sample.csv', { target: '_blank' } %>
```

Locally and on heroku it works , when I click on it downloaded successfully, but on digitalocean it gives an error

```
403 Forbidden nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: and what about 404 page (try to open your-site/404 in browser)?

Comment: I'm guessing you are using Nginx to proxy to your application. Sounds like it might be a problem locating the static file in relation to the proxy settings. What proxy coding are you using in your Nginx configuration file and what is the full error code in the Nginx error log?